# Iterative binary search in python

Tags: python, list

in the conditionals why don't you have to write `high = data[middle_term] - 1`. I understand why you do it in the actual if/else statements

```
data = [1,2,3,6,9,12,15,18,20]
def binary_search_algorthim(data,target):
    low = 0
    high = len(data) - 1

    while low <= high:
        middle_term = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[middle_term]:
            return True
        elif target < data[middle_term]:
            high = middle_term - 1
            print("high",high)
        elif target > data[middle_term]:
            low = middle_term + 1
            print("low", low)
    return False
```

Comment: Please format the code. select it and tytpe `ctrl-k`. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Visualize at : http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit.  `high`,`low`, and `middle_term` are indices. `data[middle_term]` is a value at an index. you are keeping track of indices not values.

Comment: @Mohib Don't mean to be mean, but along the lines of @wwii's comment, code formatting also includes your code "high = data[middle_term] -1" above, which after adding ` ` becomes `high = data[middle_term] -1`.

Answer (score 1):

`high` and `low` are not the actual numbers from your data, they just mark the place where the actual numbers are, so when you want to compare to `target` you don't compare the place and the value, you have to compare the value at the place and the value.

Hence, `target` (value) = `data[ (position) ]` (again, a value)